# jQuery Datepicker TH Year Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I already set below things for datepicker. I already added TH JS As well.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-th.js

It's showing TH Month Name & Days. But not year

```
  $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "th" ] );

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

  // Birth date
  $("#date-of-birth").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearSuffix: year+543,
    yearRange: '-100:+0',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  });
```

Because in TH.

```
 29/03/2018 (EN) -> 29/03/2561 (TH)
```

**Thai Year is Current - 543**

**[Update]**

It's showing in Year Prefix, But not in Year Range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already tried and it works
https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/rdJmyL

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/datepicker-th.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date-of-birth"></p>
```

Did I miss something?

**EDIT**

set year range `yearRange: '+443:+543'`

set current year to the end range year

```
var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setYear(currentDate.getFullYear() + 543);
$('#date-of-birth').datepicker("setDate",currentDate );
```

Comment: yes, you miss explaining what you exactly did to make it work?

Comment: I already attached my codepen to my answer. And I don't know @Julia did in he/she code. How can I explain?

Comment: Hi @TanDuong This is what currently I have. It should show year 2561

Comment: So yearRange should show 2461 to 2561. Only year issue.

Comment: If we put `yearRange: '-543'` then it only shows 1918 only

Comment: Can you check my codepen again https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/rdJmyL? `yearRange: '+443:+543',` Here is my change

Comment: @TanDuong almost near by. It should show current Year. Currently it's showing 2461 instead of 2561. Can u make this small change.

Comment: I changed my codepen https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/rdJmyL. `$('#date-of-birth').datepicker("setDate",currentDate );`

Comment: Thanks a lot @TanDuong