# How to set Year dropdown as Current thai Year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

[jQuery Datepicker TH Year Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548115/jquery-datepicker-th-year-issue)

On top of above question. I have below 2 issues.

By default it's not showing Current Year as selected. Instead of 2561 it's showing 2461.

By default if you select date. It's showing 2018.

By default, I don't want to add.

```
$('#date-of-birth').datepicker("setDate",currentDate );
```

So initial it will be empty.

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/rdJmyL

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sharing your code snippet really helps

Comment: Hi @PirateX It's here https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/rdJmyL